# image canvas didn't update properly

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am using the Tkinter library of Python for GUI.

This is an image of the initial GUI:

[image]

After people enter their email address and choose an option using the dropdown list, the program should do 3 things:

1. Perform Neural Style Transfer of the image
2. Show the original and transformed image to the user
3. Send the concatenated original and transformed images to the user's email

I have no problem with step 1. But I can't perform both step 2 and 3.

**Scenario A (Step 2 ok step 3 not ok)**

Right now, if the code to update the canvas is as such:

```
def update(self):

    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    global counter

    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(self.finish)) # First and maybe second copy.


    self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.window, width = img.width(), height = img.height())

    self.canvas.pack()
    self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = img, anchor = tkinter.NW)

    self.window.after(1000, self.update())
```

**Notice that there are parentheses after self.update() on the last line.**

Although the images are shown like this:
[image]

however, the email (step 3) is not sent due to this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/SendEmail.py", line 58, in close
    self.sendEmail()
  File "C:/Users/SendEmail.py", line 278, in sendEmail
    self.update()
  File "C:/Users/SendEmail.py", line 73, in update
    self.window.after(1000, self.update())
  File "C:/Users/SendEmail.py", line 73, in update
    self.window.after(1000, self.update())
  File "C:/Users/SendEmail.py", line 73, in update
    self.window.after(1000, self.update())
  [Previous line repeated 437 more times]
  File "C:/Users/SendEmail.py", line 71, in update
    self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = img, anchor = tkinter.NW)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2489, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2480, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 139, in __str__
    return str(self.__photo)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I understand that the recursion error is due to the parentheses after the self.update. But if I changed the code to the following, the situation reverses:

**Scenario B (step 2 not ok step 3 ok)**

Updated code to correctly write callback function:

```
def update(self):

    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    global counter

    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(self.finish)) # First and maybe second copy.


    self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.window, width = img.width(), height = img.height())

    self.canvas.pack()
    self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = img, anchor = tkinter.NW)

    self.window.after(1000, self.update)
```

This way of writing the code causes the canvas to look like this:

[image]

However, the email (step 3) could be sent.

When I close the Tkinter window, the concatenated image actually comes out on the Spyder console:
[image]

How can I make the image update in the canvas successfully without blocking the code so that the email can be sent out?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `after` needs "callback" - it means function name without `()` - `after(0, self.update)` If you use `self.update()` with `()` then it execute function at once - and if it execute again `self.update()` then you will have recursion and you can get very long error message. BTW: `comman=` in `Button` and `bind()` also need "callback"

Comment: ***"it works by updating the image in the canvas"***: As it stands, you **don't** update the image, you create a **new** `Canvas` packing beneath the previous one. Is this intentional?